# Cannot find name 'browser'.ts(2304)

Tags: jestjs, mocha.js, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I used webdriverIO and Mocha as e2e test tools.

types field in `tsconfig.json` configured like the below:
`"types": ["node", "webdriverio", "@wdio/mocha-framework", "expect-webdriverio", "mocha"]`

the code worked well several months ago, but there is an error occurs these days, and I did nothing changes

ts error:
`Cannot find name 'browser'.ts(2304)`

when I run test cases in terminal, also get error like the below:
`[0-0] 2024-03-13T08:42:20.199Z WARN @wdio/mocha-framework: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on` browser`object that is not fully initialised.`browser`object has only`capabilities`and some flags like`isMobile`. Helper files that use other` browser`commands have to be moved to`before `hook.`

I googled the issue but seems like their solution doesn't work for me.

I want to fix the ts error and run test cases without error.

Can anybody give me some advice? thanks in advance. please let me know if any other info is needed.